# Unable To Access JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I have a JSONP object which has been retrieved using ajax. The data returned is...

```
{"example.COM":{"0":[94,57],"1":[94,57],"2":[94,57],"4":[94,54],"target":"example.com","categories":{"301":3,"304":22,"501":97}}}
```

The only issue is that I can't access the JSON object with my javascript code. It is returned through a callback and dumped into the variable `data`.

I have tried...

- `data.example.com`, returns undefined
- `data["example.com"]`, returns undefined

Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, `data["example.COM"]` is not the same as `data["example.com"]`

Comment: For the first one you are trying to access `data --> example --> com`. For both of them, you need to check your capitalization.